# Что выведет программа

Tags: c, функции

Дан код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int X = 3;
void Proc1 (int *Y) {
    *Y = 6;
printf("Внутри Proc1, X: %d, Y: %d\n",X,*Y);
}
int Proc2 (int *Y, int Z) {
int X = 7;
Proc1 (&X);
Proc1 (Y);
*Y = 3;
printf("Внутри Proc2, X: %d, Y: %d, Z: %d\n",X,*Y,Z);
return (*Y + Z);
}
int main()
{
int A = 1, B = 3, C = 5;
C = Proc2 (&A,B);
printf("В итоге, A: %d, B: %d, C: %d\n",A,B,C);
return(0);
}
```

И следующий вывод к нему:

```
Внутри Proc1, X: 3, Y: 6
Внутри Proc1, X: 3, Y: 6
Внутри Proc2, X: 6, Y: 3, Z: 3
В итоге, A: 3, B: 3, C: 6
```

Объясните почему вывелись такие числа и Proc1 напечаталась дважды

Answer (score 2, accepted):

См. комментарии...

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int X = 3;

void Proc1 (int *Y) {
    *Y = 6;
    // Здесь X - это const int X = 3 выше; выведет 3 и 6
    printf("Внутри Proc1, X: %d, Y: %d\n",X,*Y);
}

int Proc2 (int *Y, int Z) {
    int X = 7;         // Это X локальное, перебивает в Proc2 имя глобального X
    Proc1 (&X);        // Первый вывод, при этом X получает значение 6
    Proc1 (Y);         // Второй вывод, *Y получает значение 6
    *Y = 3;            // и тут же переписывается тройкой

    // Так что выводится X == 6, Y == 3 и Z, переданное в Proc2 (в main передается 3)
    printf("Внутри Proc2, X: %d, Y: %d, Z: %d\n",X,*Y,Z);
    // Возврат значения 3+Z, (или в main - 6...)
    return (*Y + Z);
}

int main()
{
    int A = 1, B = 3, C = 5;
    C = Proc2 (&A,B);
    // A == 3, B == 3, C == 6
    printf("В итоге, A: %d, B: %d, C: %d\n",A,B,C);
    return(0);
}
```

Все ясно или что-то дообъяснить?

Comment: Непонятно с Proc1(&X). Х получает значение 6 после первого вывода, но во втором выводе Х не будет меняться?

Comment: И Х получит значение 6 из *Y?

Comment: Да, `X` во втором вызове не будет меняться.

Comment: Да, в первом вызове X получает значение через параметр *Y.